# On the Boundedness of Muckenhoupt $A_{1}$ Weights Near Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

We say that a locally integrable $\omega(x)>0$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an Muckenhoupt $A_{1}$ weight if ${\bf{M}}\omega(x)\leq C\cdot\omega(x)$ a.e. for some constant $C>0$, where ${\bf{M}}$ is the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function. And the infimum of all such $C>0$ is denoted by $[\omega]_{A_{1}}$.

Now my question is that, for $\omega\in A_{1}$, is necessarily that
\begin{align*}
\|\omega\|_{L^{\infty}(\{|x|>M\})}<\infty
\end{align*}
for some $M>0$?

Note that I am **not** asking if $\|\omega\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}<\infty$, for $\omega(x)=\log(1/|x|)$, $|x|<1/e$ and $\omega(x)=1$ otherwise, it is a standard fact that $\omega\in A_{1}$.

What I am asking is about the boundedness of such $\omega$ near infinity.

A well-known $A_{1}$ weight is given by $\omega(x)=1/|x|^{\eta}$ for $0\leq\eta<n$, but then this is bounded.

It seems that there are few examples of concrete $A_{1}$ weights, so I cannot come out with examples, any help is appreciated.

In fact, I am more interested in asking if the following is true for $\omega\in A_{1}$:
\begin{align*}
\sup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}^{n}}\left(\int_{B_{1}(z)}\omega(x)dx\right)<\infty?
\end{align*}

Comment: At the moment you are imposing a Muckenhoup constant $\leq 1$. Is that intentional? Or do you want to allow for some constant $C>0$?

Comment: Typo once again, sorry, sorry.

Comment: The first claim looks false to me. Have you tried to look at a periodic version of your $\log$ counterexample?

Comment: That example you can check with *Classical Fourier Analysis 3rd Edition* by Loukas Grafakos, page 507.

Comment: I meant, that one can maybe construct a counterexample to the "bounded at infinity" question using a periodic version of the $\log$ example.

Comment: Right, define $\omega(x)$ to be the $2/e$-periodic extension of $$ \omega(x) = \log(1/\vert  x \vert), \quad x\in [-1/e, 1/e).$$ For small radii this is fine (as it was for the original function). For large radii, we can use periodicity and the fact that $\omega(x) \geq 1$ to find a suitable constant to make things work. It is already too late for me to work out the proof, but maybe you can try to do that (need to go to bed).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, Just computed for a while, your counterexample works for the first claim. Unfortunately, it satisfies $\sup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}\omega(B_{1}(z))<\infty$. I am trying to come out with counterexample for the second claim.

Comment: I'd try to use bumps to construct a counterexample. Let $\omega_n(x) = \max\{ \frac{n}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}, 1 \}$ and then consider $$ \omega(x) =\begin{cases} \omega_n(x-e^n), & x\in [e^n-n^2, e^n + n^2], \\ 1, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$ We have $[w_n]_{A_1} \leq \frac{3}{2}$ (crude estimate) and so small radii should be fine. The exponential distance between the bumps should eliminate all the issues for large radii.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, does your new $\omega$ serve as a counterexample for the second claim that $\sup\omega(B_{1}(z))<\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it would (if I did not make a mistake and it is really in $A_1$). Because $$ \int_{e^n-1}^{e^n+1} \omega = \int_{e^n-1}^{e^n+1} \omega_n(x-e^n) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{n}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}.$$

Comment: I made some rough computations to show that my weight is in $A_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those computations are very crude, I did not attempt to optimize constants. Feel free to edit if this bothers you.

Define $\omega_n(x) = \max\{ \frac{n}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}, 1 \}$ and

$$ \omega(x) = \begin{cases} \omega_n(x-4^n),& x\in [4^n-n^2, 4^n+n^2] \text{ for some } n\geq 3, \\ 1,& \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

First we consider small radii. That means, $r$ is so small that it intersects at most one of the intervals $[4^n-n^2, 4^n+n^2]$. Then it is enough to check that $\omega_n$ is in $A_1$ (after a shift). We distinguish two cases. If $0< r< x_0 $

$$ \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x_0+r}^{x_0+r} \omega_n(x) \leq 1 +\frac{1}{2r} \int_{x_0+r}^{x_0+r} \frac{n}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}
= 1+\frac{n}{r} \left( \sqrt{x_0+r} - \sqrt{x_0-r} \right)
= 1+\frac{n}{r} \frac{2r}{\sqrt{x_0+r} + \sqrt{x_0-r}} \leq \frac{2n}{\sqrt{x_0}} \leq 3 \omega_n(x_0). $$

On the other hand, if $0<x_0\leq r$ (if $x_0=0$ it is trivial as $\omega_n(0)=\infty$ and by symmetry we can assume that $x_0>0$)

$$ \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r} \omega_n(x) \leq 1+\frac{1}{2r} \int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r} \frac{n}{\sqrt{\vert x \vert}}
=1+ \frac{1}{2r} \left( \int_0^{r-x_0} \frac{n}{\sqrt{x}} + \int_{0}^{x_0+r} \frac{n}{\sqrt{x}} \right)
= 1+\frac{n}{r} \left( \sqrt{r-x_0} + \sqrt{x_0+r} \right)
\leq 1+\frac{n}{r} (1+\sqrt{2}) \sqrt{r} 
\leq (2+\sqrt{2}) \omega_n(x_0). $$

Finally, we consider large radii. Let $x\in [4^n, 4^{n+1}]$ and $4^m < r \leq 4^{m+1}$ for $m\geq n-1$. Then, we just integrate over all bumps that we could possibly reach

$$ \frac{1}{2r} \int_{x_0-r}^{x_0+r} \omega(x) \leq 1 + \frac{1}{2r} \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} 2 \int_0^{\sqrt{j}} \frac{j}{\sqrt{x}}
\leq 1 + \frac{2}{r} \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} j^2 \leq 1+ \frac{2}{4^m} \frac{(m+1) (m+2) (2m+3)}{6} \leq 4 \leq 4 \omega(x_0). $$

The remaining cases work similarly. Thus, we get that $\omega$ is indeed in $A_1$.

Note that this provides a counterexample as

$$ \int_{4^n}^{4^n+1} \omega(x) = \int_{4^n}^{4^n+1} \omega_n(x-4^n) = \int_0^1 \frac{n}{\sqrt{x}} = 2n. $$